# Error in reporting service

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Error when trying to deploy shared dataset.
Actually, I am very new to this SQL Server Reporting Service. I have created a data source and deployed it successfully. and created a dataset to link a stored procedure with the application and tried to deploy it but it gave the error.

> Error : Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The feature: "Shared dataset" is not supported in this edition
>   of Reporting Services

Comment: You will not get better response with this limited information, please add more details about the specific issue

Comment: can you provide some more information what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty descriptive. Your SQL Server version does not allow shared datasets. Either is poorly configured or is not supported. Most probably it is the later, check the MS doc.

As long as no info is provided on specific sql server version installed, I link you the 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016